# Retag Request: Revert golang changes

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request

In November 2009, Go, a new programming language, was announced. The primary web site is golang.org.

People soon started using Stack Overflow to ask questions about Go. A primary tag for questions about a programming language should use the language name e.g. go, c, c++, java, etc. Some people used the web site name, golang, in addition to or instead of the language name go. From time to time, editors and moderators have cleaned up the tags, adding the tag go and/or deleting the tag golang as necessary. Comments were also left asking people to standardize on the go tag. As recently as March 13, there were 117 questions tagged go, 3 of which were also tagged in error with golang.

List the active questions tagged with go and golang: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=go+golang&sort=active. You will see that, on March 19, Stack Overflow user 109070, Hannson, is adding the tag golang to questions tagged with go; he's made 55 changes so far.

Please ask Hannson to stop and please revert his changes. If a question is tagged with golang, it should also be tagged with go, then, all golang tags should be deleted, leaving just the go tag.

Comment: Obviously angling for a Taxonomist badge

Comment: You go, ... well, boy.

Comment: He's got a Taxonomist badge now. boooo. (Moderators, please consider going into the DB and removing it! We should not encourage bad mass-tagging.)

Answer (score 15):

I'm [Hannson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/109070/hannson), Stack Overflow user 109070.

I just got an email from the SO team with a link to this post and I wrote them an apology which I'd also like to make public. I believe in honesty and this go vs golang thing was my mistake. I was unaware that moderators had been trying to get rid of the golang tag and I thought adding it would help users and search engines to find Go articles because "golang" is easier to find than "go", which is extremely common. The fact that I could get a "taxonomist" badge while doing what I thought was right only encouraged me to continue doing it.

This is the only (and hopefully last) suspension I've gotten on my SO account and I'm writing this to redeem myself and hoping you won't hold a grudge against me for this.

The reason I bother to write all of this is because I do care!

**Here below is the email I sent to the SO team**

---

Hi there

I'm sorry for the inconvenience I may have caused and will not let it happen again. Let me be the first to say that I'm aware that Stackoverflow is not an MMORPG in which you go on quests for badges. The reason why I began tagging questions with the golang tag has roots to my frustration while searching for golang articles on Google (and other search engines). This ridiculously common term has really bad signal/noise ratio and by tagging with a more specific term it would encourage the use of "golang" and standardize it to help users find articles through search engines.

I was under the impression that was doing good things for the community by helping people find golang articles but I do admit that the "taxonomist" badge was a sweet bonus but like I wrote above, it was not the main goal. How ever, I'd still like to see this tag used in the future although I doubt it'll ever take off.

In the future I will try to be more careful and do things the right way; in collaboration with the SO community and I sincerely hope you won't hold a grudge against me for my mistake because this was all done in good faith. Looking back I can see how this made me look like a jerk, so I ask you and our community to please accept my apology.

Best regards,
Hannes Baldursson aka Hannson

Answer (score 4):

Well spotted. Sigh. I've reverted the edits (the language is indeed "go", not "golang"). It'll need the dev-team to de-badge them, though. I'll "make enquiries" ;-p

(I *absolutely* agree that random editing purely to get taxonomist is a bad idea)

Comment: Good call Marc.