# Changing [go] tag to [golang]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request

This is slightly related to this topic, where a user was asked to stop adding extraneous tags to a post:

[Retag Request: Revert golang changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42909/retag-request-revert-golang-changes)

I can't help but think he was right though in what he was doing (also, has 13 upvotes). As someone who's recently started learning Go, it's impossible to google for.

Sample searches, that turn up close to zero relevant results.

- https://www.google.com/search?q=convert+byte+array+to+int+array+go
- https://www.google.com/search?q=go+quit+a+program

These turn up results for Java etc.

The word "golang" is much less likely to turn up synonyms or results that happen to use the word "go".

Would it be possible to change the tag to make [go](/questions/tagged/go) a synonym of [golang](/questions/tagged/golang) instead of the other way around?

Comment: I'm opposed to this; it's not our fault Google chose an awful name for their language that their search engine can't even find. Using a tag search in SO's own search engine works fine. (well, not your first example, presumably because no such questions exist. what does xoring a string even mean?)

Comment: Why the downvotes? It's a legitimate question, even if you disagree

Comment: @Wooble It kind-of is our problem, since we are concerned with SEO. If people don't find Stack Overflow answers because they're searching for "golang" instead of "go", that's an issue.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences

Comment: I'm in favor—even within the Mountain View Chocolate Factory, it's often referred to as golang for easier searching.

Comment: "*As someone who's recently started learning Go, it's impossible to google for.*" How ironic ;)

Comment: Wouldn't `go-lang` be a better name?

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby Thing is that everywhere the golang alternative is used, it's written like that. Not go-lang. I don't think we should be creating yet another alternative spelling.

Comment: Could we get referrer data for SO questions and see which people are using more

Comment: I am in favor. It's true that "it's Google's fault" but the Go community has evolved to use golang precisely for searchability. SEO on Stack does matter, it's how most people get their answers.

Comment: The language is named Go. It doesn't have any worse Googlability than D, which doesn't even have Dlang as a synonym tag. Using golang just destroys the googlability of Golang, India. (The official suggestion is to use the phrase "Go language" in searches. That does help.)

Comment: Yup, the language is Go. It irritates people when newcomers show up on the mailing list asking about "golang" or "Google Go" and tagging it golang here would exacerbate the problem.

Comment: How is this any different from the `C` tag?  Is that going to be changed to `Clang`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: That's even worse, because we already have a tag called [clang].

Answer (score 7):

The language name is **Go**, not golang. It's fine to use golang when a context makes it very difficult for Go to be used properly, but StackOverflow is not such a case:

- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=go+convert

Answer (score -2):

Since in practice I've heard people having practical problem of searching for answers with the term Go.

And since I haven't heard of problems in the other direction.

I think the term `golang` should win, on technical merits. Regardless to the question about the "correct" name for the language.

Using `go` would hurt the workflow of some people, and using `golang` would not hurt the workflow of other people (albeit it might be considered inaccurate, or bad taste). So I believe the name `golang` should be preferred.